# (Left to itself), what would be the motion of dipole with and without electric field?

Tags: electric-fields, dipole

There is a uniform electric field and I have kept a positive and a negative charge (in the electric field) separated by a small distance, now left to itself what will be the final configuration of this system? How will it reach it and what is the math behind it? Will I get different results in the absence of electric field? 
PS - This is not a homework question

Comment: Also I think it is not a homework, but I think it is still unclear (what is another close reason). Elaborate the setting more clearly.

Comment: i have, just now

Answer (score 1):

If your dipole is moving in a straight line it will just keep going.

If it is rotating, there will be radiation of EM energy due to the accelerating charge. This will slowly remove energy from the dipole so its rotation will slow down.

See for example [this](http://www.phys.boun.edu.tr/~sevgena/p202/docs/Electric%20dipole%20radiation.pdf)